How is length adjustment calculated if you have a pull-up resistor?
Let's say that I have a point A and a point B. In between there must be a conductor. It must have a certain length. But I have to hang on to a pull-up resistor as well. But I can do that at point C.
How is length adjustment calculated if you have a pull-up resistor?
Should I look at the length A to B, A to C or the sum of several lengths?
It sounds more logical if the length should be between A to B because that is where the signal should be transported between the source pad and the destination pad. But I'm not sure.

https://i.ibb.co/LpVK8h3/Sk-rmbild-2024-05-19-195655-1.png
Update:
The track is a data signal track for a DDR3L memory.

Processor: STM32MP151AAC3
Track: DDR_BA1 (The address data signal)
IBIS model: Available
Reference CAD model: Available
Impedence: 55 ohm
Length matching: Yes
Guidlines: DDR memory routing from ST


Is there anything in the datasheet about layout guidelines?

What signal is it? A clock signal, a data signal? What is the required margin? What is the pull up strength?

The pull up does not change the length of the signal trace (since the signal does not travel through the pull up).  It does however create a stub and section of the line where the impedance is not constant, so you must keep it short enough relative to your rise time that you can ignore the impedance discontinuity.

Is it just a pull-up - or is it a termination? If the latter it should be close to the end of the trace.

@Colin I have added new a guidline reference URL

@VoltageSpike Data signal, 55 ohm impedence, lengthmatching yes. The pull-up i 3.3V

@KevinWhite It's a pull-up of 56 ohm

56 ohm is not just a pull-up but a full terminator of the transmission line. The DDR pin is actually the stub, it would seem.

@TimWilliams So should I compute the length between BGA ball to BGA ball. Both the MCU and DDR have a BGA package. According to the documentation, both length equalization and impedance should be done.

I think the only thing that matters is the length of the stub, you probably wouldn't want to make it too long. If you are doing something in the GHz range it would probably matter. In the 100MHz range it probably isn't a big deal because the resistance of the trace wouldn't matter but the inductance would.
It also matters if the trace needs to be impedance matched. In which you could simulate the stub and see if it makes a difference.
